# VB.NET Equivalent of C# Mask.NullString(str).Length

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I've come across code in a library that I want to use that I have never seen before (probably because I don't use c# all that much) and can't find any documentation on. It doesn't work in VB.NET and I'm not even sure of what it does so that I could go about doing it some different way. The expression is `Mask.NullString(str).Length`. Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of `Mask.NullString` that I [found on the web](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aiBKi3MXe1KsJ%3ajayrock.googlecode.com/hg/src/Common/Mask.cs%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) looks like this:

```
public static string NullString(string actual) {
    return actual == null ? string.Empty : actual;
}
```

I'm not an expert in VB, but I think it translates to this:

```
if(str, String.Empty).Length
```

Comment: Thank you so much...How embarrassing

Comment: and I think the correct translation to vb.net would be `IIf(str, str, String.Empty).Length`

Comment: `IIf(str IsNot Nothing, str, String.Empty()).Length`

Comment: @Eliezer I used a null coalesce operator instead. It is available in VB 9 and up. In C# it would be `(actual ?? string.Empty).Length`.